# gETH on AWS what is required to collect all Transfer events from block 0 to current after node sync

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I need to save all Transfer events of the blockchain in order to later on build up a balance tracker for all wallets I wanna fetch. I was thinking about running gEth on AWS but I never did anything with gETH before.

What would be the best setup and version of gETH in order to later on be able to fetch Transfer events from block 0 on via web3?

Answer (score 1):

You just need latest OS (either windows or linux), geth latest version(1.10.4) with a minimum of 500GB disk space(at present ETH blockchain need 400GB+ disk space).
Best place to start : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum

Comment: thank you, I know the hardware requirements for it, but what type of gETH to I need to install in order to be able to later on fetch all events like Transfer events from block 0 to current? There are different types of gETH installements. Like light, archieve and so on.

Comment: You need geth with archive mode

Comment: You might also need to add load parameter --txlookuplimit=0 to index all transactions. Otherwise getTransaction returns null for older transactions.

Comment: what disc space is required for archieve mode?

Comment: Archive mode it is 6TB+. you can track it at https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/